# After pressing, I think, "y", in Edit mode, my cursor looks weird. Does anyone know why?

Tags: mouse

It looks like a cross, and makes me feel slightly uncomfortable and afraid something is wrong.
[image]

Comment: Hello :). Nothing is wrong, this is the regular cursor visible in Edit mode.

Comment: ...Wait really?

Comment: just press tab -> then you are in object mode again